# Selenium not detecting element Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape the Bing AI chat website, but my selenium isn't detecting the website or any elements on it at all. I tried the same with another website, like Wikipida and it works fine, but as soon as I try anything else it stops working. I have also tried increasing the wait time, and it has done absolutely nothing. Any idea as to what I can do?

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import os
    
    
    
    
    
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    
    # Adding argument to disable the AutomationControlled flag
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    
    # Exclude the collection of enable-automation switches
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    
    # Turn-off userAutomationExtension
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    
    # Setting the driver path and requesting a page
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bing+AI&showconv=1&FORM=hpcodx')
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tone-options"]/li[3]/button'))).click()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be tricky, because Bing DOM structure is based on `shadow-root`s.
That means that to get access to inner elements structure, you must access to shadow-root host first.

[What is shadow-root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot)

In your case, precise button is placed on 4th level of `shadow-root`s

1. 1st host has locator `.cib-serp-main`
2. 2nd host has locator `#cib-conversation-main`
3. 3rd host has locator `cib-welcome-container`
4. 4th host (where your buttons are located) is `cib-tone-selector`

4th host is placed inside 3rd, 3rd is placed inside 2nd, 2nd places inside 1st.

You can access to `shadow-root` content by getting `shadowRoot` property from element via JS.

```py
url = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bing+AI&showconv=1&FORM=hpcodx"

driver.get(url)
app_root = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'cib-serp-main')))
first_level_shadow_root = get_shadow_root(app_root)
second_level_shadow_root = get_shadow_root(first_level_shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, 'cib-conversation-main'))
third_level_shadow_root = get_shadow_root(second_level_shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'cib-welcome-container'))
fourth_level_shadow_root = get_shadow_root(third_level_shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'cib-tone-selector'))
precise_button = fourth_level_shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tone-options .tone-precise')
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Example:

```
shadow_root_1 = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cib-serp-main').shadow_root
shadow_root_2 = shadow_root_1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'cib-action-bar').shadow_root
shadow_root_3 = shadow_root_2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'cib-text-input').shadow_root

textarea = shadow_root_3.find_element(By.ID, 'searchbox')
textarea.send_keys("Your text here")
time.sleep(1)
textarea.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Full code(tested):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import json
import os
import sys
import pickle
from requests import Session
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from Screenshot import Screenshot
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pyperclip
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromeOptions = Options()
# chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless') # show or hide...
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--window-size=1280,720")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
chromeOptions.add_argument('-–allow-file-access-from-files')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-site-isolation-trials')

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)

try:
    browser.get("https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bing+AI&showconv=1&FORM=hpcodx")
    time.sleep(10)

    # Find the element by link text and click it
    try:
        element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Accept')]")
        element.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))

    time.sleep(10)

    shadow_root_1 = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cib-serp-main').shadow_root
    shadow_root_2 = shadow_root_1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'cib-action-bar').shadow_root
    shadow_root_3 = shadow_root_2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'cib-text-input').shadow_root

    textarea = shadow_root_3.find_element(By.ID, 'searchbox')
    textarea.send_keys("Your text here")
    time.sleep(1)
    textarea.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    time.sleep(10)

#     ob = Screenshot.Screenshot()
#     ob.full_screenshot(browser, save_path=r'.', image_name='page_source.png', is_load_at_runtime=True, load_wait_time=1)
    print("DONE")
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", str(e))
finally:
    browser.quit()
```